# limit Resource Group cost - Azure

Tags: azure

I need to limit Azure Resource Group to 3000usd

When the limit is exceeded I need to stop all.

Can I do this automatically?

Can I receive alerts when the cost is on 2800usd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have spending limits on the subscription and receive alerts at certain thresholds, but I dont think there's anything built-in that would stop the resouces. Many of the resources can not be stopped anyway (app services, azure sql dtu model, managed disks, etc).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/cost-mgt-alerts-monitor-usage-spending